# How do I maximize the function $z \mapsto y^T z$ on the set $\{z : \|z\|_1 = 1.\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose $y$ is some vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for which $\|y\|_1 > 1$. I am trying to show that there exists some $z$ with $\|z\|_1 = 1$ such that $y^T z > 1$. I was thinking to try to maximize the function $z \mapsto y^T z$ on the set $\{z : \|z\|_1 = 1\}$. I know that this function is continuous and the set is compact, but I don't think I can use lagrange multipliers here because the $L_1$ norm is not differentiable at any point where $0$ is one of the coordinates.

Could I have a hint about what to try here?

Comment: Let $y=(\frac 12,\frac 12)^T$. For every $z\in \mathbb R^2$ with $\|z\|_1=1$ we get $y^Tz=\frac 12(z_1+z_2) \leq \frac 12\|z\|_1=\frac 12$. So your hypothesis is false.

Comment: For the correct hypothesis, we need this: if $1\leq p \leq \infty$ and $\frac1p +\frac1q = 1$, then $$\sup_{\|z\|_p=1}y^Tz=\|y\|_q$$